# Embedding bokeh plot and datatable in flask

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I'm trying to both embed a bokeh plot AND a bokeh datatable in a flask-generated website (same page) using some of the provided examples in the Bokeh docs. Both components work standalone. I tried to put them together via gridplot, but that seems only to work with plots, and a datatable is a 'widget'.
I'm probably missing some very basic concept, but any pointers or links to examples are appreciated

Comment: There's also `HBox`/`hplot` and `VBox`/`vplot`

Comment: hplot and vplot: same contraints, but HBox/VBox worked, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I like to do this is to use the full power of the [`embed.components`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html#bokeh.embed.components) method and pass in a dictionary of plot objects and then render them wherever I need in my html template.

I call components as follows:

```
from bokeh.embed import components
script, div_dict = components({"plot": plot, "table": table})
```

My `div_dict` looks like this:

```
# {"plot": plot_div, "table": table_div})
```

I then pass this dict and the script into my template context and use it something like this:

```
<body>
   {{ plot_div }}
   {{ table_div }}
   {{ script }}
</body>
```

Here's an example from the bokeh examples: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_multiple_responsive.py#L26

Comment: How does this work if you have 2 plots and a widget (where the plots plots are controlled by the same widget). I'm trying to exactly the above, but once I put them into separate components (so I can place anywhere in my HTML template) the relationship between the widgets and plots appears to break...

Comment: Are you using bokeh server or JS callbacks?