# Embedded Bokeh DataTable not showing in Django

Tags: python, django, datatable, bokeh

I have developed a Django web application showing interactive maps generated by Bokeh, and sent to the templates as script/div using 'components' (from bokeh.embed). All items (figure, slider, title) are shown correctly except DataTable, which I can show in a standalone document or in Jupyter, but not with 'components'.

I have read [Bokeh DataTable not show in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721402/bokeh-datatable-not-show-in-flask), [Embedding bokeh plot and datatable in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298029/embedding-bokeh-plot-and-datatable-in-flask) and other threads, which helped me to fix the JS/CSS links, but it did not help with my problem.

I tried to wrap the DataTable inside different modules, like Panel, WidgetBox, etc., after reading https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4507, without success. For simplicity, I used example data with no link to my data to generate the table in a separate Django view, and created a separate template.

I have run out of ideas for now. I know that widgets in Bokeh have had rendering issues, so I am guessing my issue could be related to those issues, but more likely to my lack of knowledge. The code is below.

**DJANGO VIEW**:

```
def datatable_test(request):

data = dict(
    dates=[date(2014, 3, i + 1) for i in range(10)],
    downloads=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date", formatter=DateFormatter()),
    TableColumn(field="downloads", title="Downloads"),
]

data_table_mth = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

layout = column(
    Spacer(width=100),
    WidgetBox(data_table_mth),
    )

script_table, div_table = components(layout)
output_file("DATATABLE TEST.html")
show(layout)

return render(request, 'integrated/datatable_test.html', {'script_table': script_table,'div_table': div_table})
```

**DJANGO TEMPLATE**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

  {{ script_table | safe }}

</head>

<body>
    <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-success">
            <div class="box-body">
                {{ div_table | safe }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Output as embedded table is blank:
[output as embedded table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4EJq.png)

Output as standalone html works:
[output as standalone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi8AO.png)

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the browser's javascript console?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing, it is working now on a separate template and with a separate view, but not as part of the original view/template. Let me dig a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bigreddot suggested, I opened the browser console, showing the following error messages when the DataTable is embedded in its original view/template:

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2yfY.png)

Comment: If you've set `reorderable=True` you will need to load that jq library yourself manually. That's documented somewhere, but perhaps not prominently enough. Perhaps your other template does load it, and the new one does not. Or perhaps you have not enabled `reorderable` in the other case.

Comment: I found the error: I didn't load the jQuery script links correctly. Using Ajax links  <!--jquery CDN-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> solved the issue, at least partially. Now the DataTable is showing. I have additional issues, but with the browser's console and Google I'll find the way. I think that `reorderable` is set to True by default for DataTable in Bokeh, and it is the way I need it. How can I thank you?